# Error: File 'circuitikz.sty' not found

Tags: errors, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

When using `circuitikz` to draw circuits using the following command

```
\usepackage{circuitikz}
```

gives

```
LaTeX Error: File 'circuitikz.sty' not found.
```

Comment: Do you have it installed?

Comment: @bombcar How to install it?

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu  that would be `sudo aptitude install texlive-pictures`. Under Windows, if you use Miktex you should use the [Package Manager](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html)